# Tcl 8.4 array key setting cannot accept inline function call

Tags: arrays, tcl

In other dynamic typed, interpeted languages (Ruby, PERL...), one can defined a key in a hash as an inline of a function call. For example (in Ruby:

```
a[ foo(1) ] = bar
```

I have tried to do the same in Tcl 8.4, but failed, see tclsh log below:

```
% proc add1 { x } { expr {$x + 1 } }
% array set p {}
% set p( [add1 1]) 0
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
```

Needsless to say, that I assign a variable to the output of of add1 1, and use the variable value, it does work:

```
% set a [add1 1]
2
% set p($a) 0
0
```

It is a style issue, no doubt, but I like inlining functions, and not using intermediate vriables.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

It's not really 'pretty' as such, but you can use `eval` to do something like that:

```
eval "set p([add1 1]) 0"
```

First, you give the string `"set p([add1 1]) 0"` to `eval` and since it is between quotes, you get a first level of substitution: `[add1 1]` is evaluated before being passed which means the final string passed to `eval` is `set p(2) 0`. `eval` then evaluates this.

---

EDIT:

Actually, it works without eval too, your error struck me as strange but didn't pay much attention to a detail. You need to remove the space after the first paren:

```
set p([add1 1]) 0
```

Otherwise, `set` interprets that you're giving the two arguments `[add1 1])` and `0` to the variable name `p(`.

Comment: Yup, that is what I was looking for...
Thanks!

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please consider accepting it. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way it works, which uses `array set`:

```
array set p {}
array set p [list [add1 1] 0]
array set p [list [add1 2] 0]
parray p
```

Output:

```
p(2) = 0
p(3) = 0
```